# Ignore packages, node_modules, bin, obj, folders globally in Visual SVN server

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

Trying to automate the process across repositories, in Visual Studio ecosystem.

> Is it possible to ignore packages, node_modules, bin, obj, folders
>   globally in Visual SVN server, across all repositories, so that user
>   do not see the changes in Tortoise SVN client.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest SVN client versions, you can use the [`svn:global-ignores`](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#repos-dictated-config) property.

However, in Active Directory environment it may be easier to rely on [`global-ignores` runtime configuration option on the client-side](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/confarea/). You can specify `global-ignores` in the Windows Registry and hence use Group Policy to push this configuration to all Visual Studio and VisualSVN users.